Idiomatic ways of using tuples and std::tie
I am trying to implement the modular multiplicative inverse using the extended Euclidean algorithm in C++. In Python, the code for this is concise and idiomatic, using tuple unpacking:
def inv_modulo(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    _s, s = 1, 0
    _t, t = 0, 1

    while a % b != 0:
        q, r = divmod(a, b)
        _s, s = s, _s - q * s
        _t, t = t, _t - q * t
        a, b = b, r

    return s

I want to replicate this behavior in C++ and have written the following code:
long long inv_modulo(long long a, long long b) {
    long long old_s = 1, s = 0;
    long long old_t = 0, t = 1;

    while (a % b != 0) {
        auto [q, r] = std::lldiv(a, b);
        std::tie(old_s, s) = std::make_tuple(s, old_s - q * s);
        std::tie(old_t, t) = std::make_tuple(t, old_t - q * t);
        std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, r);
    }
    return s;
}

I have three specific questions about this implementation:

Is this C++ code equivalent to the Python code shown?
Is this code considered idiomatic in C++ programming?
Is there a performance penalty for writing the code this way compared another approach, for example using temporary variables for the intermediate steps of the computation?


For this specific case (old, current, new_value assignation), there is std::exchange (C++14). (old_s = std::exchange(s, old_s - q * s))

Thanks, I think that is what I was really looking for! If you want to go ahead and post your solution, I will accept it!

For trivial types such as integral types, if there is overhead, it would be small; but for non-trivial types (as std::string), unless optimized, there are extra copies.


yes 2. I would say no, but code is ok for me. 3. extra copies involved with the extra tuple (compared to multiple simple assignation) (relying to the optimizer to remove the overhead).


Would the std::exchange create extra copies as well?

It works, but I would just use std::div in C++; it has overloads for all signed integral types larger than int. And I would use std::int64_t for fixed size intent across platforms, or std::intmax_t to use the largest supported signed integer. std::tie is not popular among C++ programmers, but I like your use-case. The right hand side must be a std::tuple- as std::make_tuple does. But since C++17, you can just do std::tuple{a,b} for the same result.

@Red.Wave: tuple{a, b} is even superior with order of evaluation guaranteed (std::tuple{string1 + string2, std::move(string1)} (parameters order is so important though, and might be not the "natural" order :-/ )

Integral types are fundamental data types. Therefore, they are also trivial. That makes them first rank candidates for all kinds of optimizations. Don't bother with optimization, if it does what it should. Check the disassembly to find out about its efficiency.

This is a summary of what @Jarod42 said in the comments, I was waiting for him to post an answer so I could accept it but since that didn't happen, here is the answer to my question.

Yes, this code is equivalent to the Python code show above.
No, this is not the idiomatic way of writting C++ code but seems like it would not bother many C++ developpers as it seems by the comments.
For trivial types this can probably be optimized away but for non-trivial types, we have an extra copy when creating a tuple and we are relying on the compiler to make the optimizations.

He also pointed out that for my use case one can use the std::exchange from C++14. This is my refactored code after the comments.
std::int64_t inv_modulo(std::int64_t a, std::int64_t b) {
  std::int64_t old_s = 1, s = 0;
  std::int64_t old_t = 0, t = 1;

  while (a % b != 0) {
    auto div_result = std::div(a, b);
    old_s = std::exchange(s, old_s - div_result.quot * s);
    old_t = std::exchange(t, old_t - div_result.quot * t);
    a = std::exchange(b, div_result.rem);
  }
  return s;
}


structural binding is a bit risky. Note that std::lldiv_t has unspecified order of fields :(. See documentation.

Why C++????? :'( I've updated the code to remove the structural binding, is this better?

AFAIK, std::tie was originally designed for exactly similar kind of use; as the left side of an assignment, though later other useful cases might've showed up. The idiom is illustrated relativity well in the OP snippet:

structured binding for decoupling tuple-like values.
std::tie on the left side of assignment
std::tuple constructor(or std::make_tuple for older standard revisions) on the right side of assignment.

std::tie creates a temporary tuple of references to elements, who need to be assigned from another tuple.
The main objectives of every program are functionally and readability. Optimization concerns only come after careful benchmarking.
